# Vertex border color/width in R graph plot

Tags: r, igraph

I am using igraph for plotting a graph in R doing something like `plot(mygraph, vertex.color = "green")`.

Is there a way to change the color and/or width of the vertices' *borders*?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check out the code below;

```
plot(all, layout=All_layout, vertex.size=2, vertex.label=V(All)$name,
vertex.color="green", vertex.frame.color="red", edge.color="grey",  
edge.arrow.size=0.01, rescale=TRUE,vertex.label=NA, vertex.label.dist=0.0,
vertex.label.cex=0.5, add=FALSE,   vertex.label.font=.001)
```

Answer (score 8):

This post is outdated. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483830/vertex-frame-width-in-r-network-plot) for a solution that works for the current version of igraph (0.6.5).

Answer (score 7):

As Sean Mc wrote above, vertex border color can be changed by using the `vertex.frame.color` parameter. It turns out that igraph provides no `vertex.frame.width` parameter, but the solution proposed [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2009-09/msg00019.html) works great for changing the border width.

Answer (score 1):

igraph does now have `vertex.frame.width` (version 1.3.5)