# Vertex frame width in R network plot

Tags: r, networking, igraph

My question follows the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759484/vertex-border-color-width-in-r-graph-plot/), about how to change the vertex frame width in igraph.

With updates in igraph, the proposed solution seems not to work anymore. Does anybody have a solution (or maybe knows another package that provides networks with changeable vertex frame width?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a new vertex shape that has a frame width parameter. It is not very hard, see an example here: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2013-03/msg00030.html

Comment: Thanks Gabor for pointing out the solution you gave on the mailing list, it's very handy! It's a pity the defaut circle shape doesn't handle that.. I made a pull request on github that implement it, following what you did in the email.

Answer (score 0):

If like myself you came back to this to find how this was solved and had to go all the way to igraph's github and my pull request, here is the way to do it now  using:

`vertex.frame.width` to define different width . Since `igraph 1.3`

```
library(igraph)
n  <-  20
g <- make_ring(n)
g$layout <- layout_in_circle
V(g)$size <- sample(10:30,n,replace=T)
#one width
plot(g,vertex.color=rainbow(n,alpha=.6)[1:n],vertex.frame.width=5)
```